# aaply: Why does aaply(data,2,class) returns "data.frame" for all columns?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a question about `aaply`. I want to check which column `is.numeric` but the return values of `aaply` are kind of unexpected. Below is example code. Why do I get `"data.frame"` for all columns (which explains why `is.numeric` is `FALSE` even for columns with numeric vectors)?

Thanks!

```
data=data.frame(str=rep("str",3),num=c(1:3))

is.numeric(data[,1])
# FALSE
is.numeric(data[,2])
# TRUE

aaply(data,2,is.numeric)
# FALSE FALSE

aaply(data,2,class)
# "data.frame" "data.frame"
```

EDIT: In other situations this produces a warning message:

```
aaply(data,2,mean)

# 1: mean(<data.frame>) is deprecated.
#    Use colMeans() or sapply(*, mean) instead.
```

Comment: Try `colwise` or `laply` - a single column extracted from a data frame is a single column data frame.

Answer (score 4):

It is the way `aaply` works, you could even use `identity` to see what is passed to each function call, a data.frame representing each column of `data`:

```
aaply(data, 2, identity)
# $num
#   num
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   3
# 
# $str
#   str
# 1 str
# 2 str
# 3 str
```

So using `aaply` the way you want, you would have to use a function that extracts the first column of each data.frame, something like:

```
aaply(data, 2, function(df)is.numeric(df[[1]]))
#   num   str 
#  TRUE FALSE
```

but it seems much easier to just do:

```
sapply(data, is.numeric)
#   str   num 
# FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic reason is that you are providing aaply with an argument of a class it is not designed to work with. The first letter of a plyr function signifies the type of argument, in this case "a" for `array`. It does work as you expect if you offer an array:

```
> xx <- plyr::aaply(matrix(1:10, 2), 2, class)
> xx
        1         2         3         4         5 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

At least that was my understanding until I read the help page. It says that dataframe input should be accepted and that an array should be the output. So you have discovered either an error in the documentation or a bug in the function. Either way, the correct place to take this up is on the ['manipulatr' Google-newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/manipulatr). There is a fair chance that @hadley will be along to clear things up, since he is a valued contributor here as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have posted on the list but my message hasn't appeared yet.

Comment: There was a discussion on the r-devel mailing list a few years ago about why the R-Core has decided to get rid of `mean.data.frame`. You will simple need to be prepared for its eventual removal. It will not be for another year or so. They generally 'deprecate' a function with warnings for a couple of versions before pulling the plug.